# Fatal error call to undefined method in woocommerce cart fetching

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using the wordpress theme "Mystile" and when i activate it and activate woocommerce i get this error in the header:

```
Fatal error:  Call to undefined method WC_Cart::get_cart_contents_count() in C:\xampp\htdocs\lol\wp-content\themes\mystile\includes\theme-woocommerce.php on line 371
```

And on line 371 is the following :

```
    <?php
    echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();
    echo '<span class="contents">' .sprintf(_n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count(),
'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count()) . '</span>';
    ?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Can you try getting a fresh install of WooCommerce from their website and installing that (rather than from the plugin section in the dashboard)?

Comment: I tried the theme with the latest manually downloaded woocommerce version in my localhost and still i found the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's a theme problem because Mystile isn't working for me either. You will have to manually install the previous version or wait for the next version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change:

echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total();

TO

echo $woocommerce->cart->wc_get_cart_total();

I Believe. ;)